# AWS S3 & Cloudfront Individial File Bandwidth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using S3 and cloudfront to deliver videos to my users, however is there a way for me to see how much bandwidth a video is using? I can't seem to see it in the aws panal its self and I've found nothing with a good search and can't see anything in there SDK. I'm posting here just to double check before I give up.

Thanks :)

Edit: I've found that you can see file usage in Cloudfront on Popular objects page and can download it to a CSV but it only shows the most popular 50 items. I also can't find anything about it on the SDK...

Comment: It should pop up in your billing page

Comment: I don't want overall usage, I want a per file usage type thing. So I can see what videos are using more bandwidth then others and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such report (bandwidth usage per file)

however it should be easy to implement it using s3 events, lambda and dynamodb (with counters)

Comment: I've just edited my post as I've found out a little more, they have the popular urls page that I think is limited to 50 of the most popular however I don't think they have anyway to grab that via an API. I'll look into s3 events and lambda. I'm new to AWS.